# Como crear un evento personalizado en javascript

Tags: javascript, eventos

Buenas, estoy creado una función que verifica el estado de una variable global, esta variable debo estar constantemente verificándola para saber si cambio su valor. La idea es que llamar esta función y que esta pueda devolver por ejemplo un evento de tipo `success()`, **`para saber cuando termino la llamada o en este caso, cuando cambio de valor la variable`**.

```
function verificar() {
    var interval = setInterval(function () {
        if (oXMLHTTP.readyState == 4) {
            //CREAR NUEVO EVENTO
        }
    }, 1000);
}

verificar().success(){
    alert('Test');
}
```

Atento a cualquier sugerencia.

Comment: ¿Donde tienes esa variable que tienes que verificar? El servidor es el que la cambia o es el usuario o cambia cuando cambia algo más?

Comment: Es una variable global que se importa desde un framework personalizado y que modifica el valor cuando termino de cargar datos. No tengo acceso a tocar nada de este feo framework.

Comment: Me suena a que intentas utilizar Ajax, pero aun no logro comprender si lo que quieres que cuando tu archivo que carga datos termine tu mandes tu función.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes ocupar un callback para saber si tu función termina.

por ejemplo algo así.

```
function verificar(callback) {
var interval = setInterval(function () {
    if (oXMLHTTP.readyState == 4) {
        //CREAR NUEVO EVENTO
        callback(true)
    }


   }, 1000);
}

    verificar(function(response){
      alert(response);
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

Lo normal es hacerlo mediante el evento `load` de `XMLHttpRequest`:

```
request.onload = () => {
  if (request.readyState === 4 && request.status === 200) {
    // debes enviar como respuesta: 'CHANGED' si la variable cambió
    if (request.responseText === 'CHANGED') {
      // variable cambió
    }
  }
};
```

Hacer peticiones cada segundo penaliza en rendimiento, ten en cuenta eso. En lugar de esto, **realiza la verificación en procesos en donde puede cambiar la variable**, de esta manera ahorras ancho de banda y memoria.

Answer (score 0):

Al parecer Intentas usar la **wep API XMLHttpRequest** si es asi porque no pruebas lo siguiente:

```
oXMLHTTP.addEventListener("load", function (){
 alert('load successful!');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Existen paradigmas como ser programacion orientada a eventos o programacion reactiva. estas crean un flujo de sucesos de una manera particular. usando un poco de ese concepto podemos hacer que los cambios de estados sean detectados.
en general todos los frameworks lo tienen.

No se cual es el framework que usas pero en [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/545817/5191755) muestran como subscribirse al evento  **oXMLHTTP.onreadystatechange**

```
function ProcessSend() 
    Set oXMLHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP.4.0")
    Set oXMLDoc = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")

    oXMLHTTP.onreadystatechange = getRef("HandleStateChange") 

    strEnvelope = "callNo="&callNo&"&exp="&exp

    call oXMLHTTP.open("POST","http://localhost:11883/ServiceCall.asmx/"&posFirm,false)'<< changed true to false here.
    call oXMLHTTP.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded")


    call oXMLHTTP.send(strEnvelope)
end function

Sub HandleStateChange 
    if(oXMLHTTP.readyState = 4) then
        dim szResponse: szResponse = oXMLHTTP.responseText
        call oXMLDoc.loadXML(szResponse)
        if(oXMLDoc.parseError.errorCode <> 0) then
                'call msgbox("ERROR")
                response = oXMLHTTP.responseText&" "&oXMLDoc.parseError.reason
                'call msgbox(oXMLDoc.parseError.reason)
        else
                response = oXMLDoc.getElementsByTagName("string")(0).childNodes(0).text
        end if

    end if
End Sub
```

Comment: el ejemplo que das es para vbscript, y por lo que entiendo se trata de una web app XMLHttp manejada desde javascript

Comment: Si, tendrias que contarnos acerca del framework. pero de seguro tiene un evento de ese tipo al cual puedes subscribirte